# JsonConvert Items by specific field

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I want to convert [HackerNews API Items](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) with Newtonsoft.

I would like to look only at the type field and then convert to the right item of the type, so I don't have all fields in all items.

I want to be able to determine the class by type and then deserialize.

Comment: Can you not just get a json to c# class and use that to create the fields?

Comment: Do you have classes for each type already? And how do you want the type string to be mapped to class type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a Crude POCO called TypeIdentifier, which has only Type to identify the Type alone and then use the original POCO.

Use [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io?share=TxWSzacZe2LD2w5geMqW) to convert any JSON to C# Classes(POCO) and use the [JsonConvert.Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) to deserialize the same.

```
public class HakernewsTypeIdentifier
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class HakerNewsStory
{
    [JsonProperty("by")]
    public string By { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("descendants")]
    public long Descendants { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("kids")]
    public long[] Kids { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public long Score { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public long Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
}

// Use Libraries like RestSharp to fetch the Data
// Find the Type
var typeID = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HakernewsTypeIdentifier>(json);
// Deserialize once again based on the Type
if(typeID.type == "story")
    var story = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HakerNewsStory>(json);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If your issue is not deserializing, but determining what you need to deserialize, then its relatively simple

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution.

**Code for deserialize**

```cs
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemType>(responseString);
switch (item.Type)
{
    case Type.Job:
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Job>(responseString);
    case Type.Story:
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Story>(responseString);
    case Type.Comment:
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Comment>(responseString);
    case Type.Poll:
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poll>(responseString);
    case Type.PollOpt:
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PollOpt>(responseString);
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

**All items classes**

```cs
public class ItemType
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public enum Type
{
    None,
    Job,
    Story,
    Comment,
    Poll,
    PollOpt,
}

public interface IItem
{
}

public class Story : IItem
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public long Descendants { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<long> Kids { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : IItem
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<long> Kids { get; set; }
    public long Parent { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Job : IItem
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Poll : IItem
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public long Descendants { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<long> Kids { get; set; }
    public List<long> Parts { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class PollOpt : IItem
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Poll { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```